# SSRS pass multiple parameters. Given Available Values. Is it possible with LIKE operator

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS Reports. I have a stored procedure to extract all the items that have been invoiced for less than 14.9% GP based on the salesman parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Lessthan15GPAlert]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @salesrep varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  distinct
    oh.CustomerCode
    , c.CustomerName
    , ohl.ProductCode
    , ohl.ProductDescription1
    , ohl.ProductDescription2
    , oh.InvoiceNumber
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), oh.InvoiceDate,126) InvoiceDate
    , ((ohl.NetPrice-ohl.AccountingCost)/ohl.NetPrice) * 100 AS GP
    , OHL.PriceSourceCode
    , OH.SellingWarehouseNumber
    , s.description
FROM OrderHistory oh 
    inner join orderhistoryline ohl on oh.CompanyID = ohl.CompanyID and oh.OrderNumber = ohl.OrderNumber
    inner join Customer c on c.CompanyID = oh.companyid and c.customercode = oh.CustomerCode
    inner join salesman s on s.companyid = c.CompanyID and s.SalesmanID = c.SalesRepOne
WHERE oh.CompanyID = '002' 
    and oh.InvoiceDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(d,-4,GetDate()),126)
    AND ((ohl.NetPrice - ohl.AccountingCost)/ohl.NetPrice) * 100 < 14.9 
    and ohl.NetPrice <> 0.00
    AND OHL.PRICESOURCECODE NOT LIKE 'M%'
    and s.description like @salesrep
    AND COALESCE(OHL.ShippedQuantity,0) <> 0
END
```

The description column in salesman table has sample data as

```
R02 702 SMITH, JOHN TSR
R07 707 FRANKLIN, ROB TSR
R04 704 SCOTT, KEVIN TSR
R04 704 PAUL, KEITH RSM
R02 702 JOSEPH, MARY TSR
R04 704 CRIPPS, ROBERT TSR
```

Keith Paul manages two locations both 702 and 704.

I have set up available values for parameter @salesrep as follows

```
| Label | Value

%SMITH%JOHN% | %SMITH%JOHN% 

%FRANKLIN%ROB% | %FRANKLIN%ROB%

%SCOTT%KEVIN% | %SCOTT%KEVIN%

%PAUL%KEITH% | %PAUL%KEITH% 

% | %  

L702 | R02%702%

L707 | R07%707%

L704 | R04%704%
```

Now, I can run the report for each salesman and each region but I also want to run for each RSM (Regional Sales Manager). Suppose I want to run everything under Keith Paul. How can I add one more in available values for parameter such as

Label  | Value

Keith Paul  | R02%702%, R04%704%

So I would get results both from 702 and 704. How can I achieve this?

```
R02 702 SMITH, JOHN TSR
R04 704 SCOTT, KEVIN TSR
R04 704 PAUL, KEITH RSM
R02 702 JOSEPH, MARY TSR
R04 704 CRIPPS, ROBERT TSR
```

Edited: I used case statement in where clause, and added Keith-Western in available values and it worked. Advise me if there is a different solution to this by changing the query.

```
WHERE oh.CompanyID = '002' 
and oh.InvoiceDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(d,-4,GetDate()),126)
AND ((ohl.NetPrice - ohl.AccountingCost)/ohl.NetPrice) * 100 < 14.9 
and ohl.NetPrice <> 0.00
AND OHL.PRICESOURCECODE NOT LIKE 'M%'
and (CASE @salesrep WHEN 'Keith-Western' then s.description end like 'R02%702%'
        or
CASE @salesrep WHEN 'Keith-Western' then s.description end like 'R04%704%'
        or s.description like @salesrep)
AND COALESCE(OHL.ShippedQuantity,0) <> 0
```

Comment: I should be able to add a SSRS subscription for each available parameter value

Comment: Possibly a good case here for a [TVP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine)

Comment: All of the sales rep data is in that single description field - sales rep, region, and position?

Comment: yes the whole thing is in one field

Comment: I think you aught to use substring to parse the key data from those strings into columns. Then you can drag and drop the name, region, location number, etc into the table wizard and easily design your report that way.

Comment: I figured it out myself. I used case in where clause.